# What is the dimension of the following function space?

Tags: vector-spaces

Construct a function space out of the following:

$v_1 = x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$

$v_2 = x^4+x^2+1$

$v_3 = x^3+x$

$v_4 = x+1$

Where the space S is defined as linear product of the $v$'s:

$S=lin(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$

What is the dimension of S? Since $v_1$ is the linear product of $v_2$ and $v_3$ and the rest of the "vectors" appear to not be linearly dependent, is the correct answer 3? (Almost seems too easy to be the correct answer).

Comment: What do you mean by "linear product of $v_2$ and $v_3$"? Assuming you are dealing with an exercise in linear algebra you won't be multiplying those!

Comment: Sometimes things are that easy. Turn “appear to be” into a definite “are” by proving linear independence.

Comment: @Dole  I guess when you write "linear product" you mean the thing that I would call a _linear combination,_ that is, you are saying that $v_1 = av_2 + bv_3$ for some scalar values $a$ and $b.$ I suggest you double-check that claim: is it really true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass from polynomials to coordinate vectors:

$$v_1\to(1,1,1,1,0)\;,\;\;v_2\to(1,0,1,0,1)\;,\;\;v_3\to(0,1,0,1,0)\;,\;\;v_4\to(0,0,0,1,1)$$

Now form the corresponding matrix with the above as *rows*, and reduce the matrix (Gauss elementary operations):

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&0\\
1&0&1&0&1\\
0&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2-R_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&0\\
0&\!-1&0&\!-1&1\\
0&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3-R_2}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&0\\
0&\!-1&0&\!-1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3\leftrightarrow R_4}\longrightarrow$$$${}$$

$$\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&0\\
0&\!-1&0&\!-1&1\\
0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$$${}$$

We see we get a matrix of rank $\;4\;$ and then the four vectors above, and thus the four original ones (the polynomials) as well,  are linearly independent, and this means

$$\dim\text{ Span}\,\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}=4$$

**Added after correction by the OP**:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1\\
1&0&1&0&1\\
0&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2-R_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&0\\
0&\!-1&0&\!-1&0\\
0&1&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3-R_2}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&0\\
0&\!-1&0&\!-1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3\leftrightarrow R_4}\longrightarrow$$$${}$$

and thus we get at once the dimension is three...

Comment: Apologies, there was an error in the question, the first vector should be a row of ones.

Comment: @Dole, just change accordingly the above...